# Оптимизация логики построения скрипта

Tags: python, рефакторинг

Написал код по заданию, но хотелось бы знать ваше мнение:  насколько верно на данном этапе я понимаю логику построения скрипта, и есть ли какие-нибудь замечания и предложения?

Задачка:

1. Напишите программу, которая будет принимать числа от пользователя и суммировать их, пока он не напишет слово «sum».
2. Когда пользователь напишет слово «sum», должна быть выведена сумма всех чисел и начат процесс заново.
3. Если пользователь напишет «exit» или «quit», программа должна быть завершена.

код:

```
ans = 0 #иниц. переменной - сумма чисел
while ans >= 0: #пока ans больше\равна 0
    ui = input("> ") #даем юзеру ввести данные
    if ui == "sum": #если sum == true
        print(ans) #вывод суммы
        ans=0 #сброс суммы
    elif ui == "quit" or ui == "exit": # +ещё если ввел quit или exit
        break #выйти из скрипта
    else: #ещё если все в теле if == false
        ans += int(ui) #посчитать сумму строки ui=input(">") и преобразовать её в int
```

Comment: числа бывают отрицательные

Comment: В целом нормально, но цикл лучше сделать "вечный": `while True:`, не надо полагаться на сумму в этом вопросе

Comment: Цикл просто сделать бесконечным `while True:`. Ну и ещё можно добавить проверку (в блок else) на то, что ввели таки число, а не белиберду.

Comment: CrazyElf, да, согласен - так надёжнее и красивее.

Comment: GrAnd, если можно поподробнее, какую именно проверку? т.е. если можно покажи, как она будет выглядеть ?

Answer (score 3):

1. пользователь может вводить отрицательные числа, поэтому условие

   ```
    while ans >= 0:
   ```

будет некорректно работать, лучше используйте бесконечный цикл `while`:

```
    while True:
```

2. проверку на разные слова можно сделать покороче:

вместо

```
elif ui == "quit" or ui == "exit":
```

сделать

```
elif ui in ["quit", "exit"]:
```

3. в условии не сказано, что числа целые, поэтому возможно лучше сделать так:

   ```
    ans += float(ui)
   ```
4. кроме того пользователь может ввести какой-то треш и тогда программа упадет при попытке перевести треш в число, можно сделать защиту:

   ```
    else: #ещё если все в теле if == false
        try:
            ans += float(ui)
        except:
            print("неизвестная команда!")
   ```
5. дельный совет от @CrazyElf - приведите для начала полученную строку к нижнему регистру, чтобы корректно обрабатывать `Sum`, `sum`, `SUM` и т.д.:

   ```
    ui = input("> ").lower() #даем юзеру ввести данные
   ```

ну или так:

```
    ui = ui.lower()
```

Comment: Я бы ещё `.lower()` где-нибудь добавил

Answer (score 1):

Вот код:

```
ans=None #ans - None ("ничего" в логике)
s=0
while ans != 'quit' and ans != 'exit': 
    ans = input("Введите число или функцию --> ").lower() #преобразовываем ввод в маленькие буквы
    if ans == "sum": print(s); ans=0 
    elif ans.isdigit() or ans.replace('-', '', 1).isdigit(): s += int(ans) 
    elif ans!= 'quit' and ans != 'exit': print('Это не число и не функция!')
```

Его я немного сократил и заметно улучшил.

Comment: Хочу заметить: при использовании `.lower()` к числам (в строке) с ними ничего не происходит.

Comment: А отрицательные числа как же?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy исправил.

Comment: `int('1_000') == 1000`. Питон умеет вводить подчёркивание в числах. Я считаю что правильно делать `try: int(ans) except ValueError:`. Любой другой способ хрупкий и сложный.

Comment: Интересно и красиво написан код. Но сейчас пока уж больно непонятен он мне) много незнакомых пока ещё буковок :)

Comment: В основном я всё прописал ;) А что непонятно? Могу объяснить

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за советы. Особая благодарность **CrazyElf и Zhihar**
Так думаю будет красивее и практичнее.

```
ans = 0 #иниц. переменной - сумма чисел
while True: #пока ans больше\равна 0
    ui = input("> ").lower() #даем юзеру ввести данные, с разным регистром (lower)
    if ui == "sum": #если sum == true
        print(ans) #вывод сумм
        ans=0 #сброс суммы
    elif ui in ["quit", "exit"]: # +ещё если ввел quit или exit
        break #выйти из скрипта
    else: #ещё если всё в теле if == false
        try: #при корректном вводе
            ans += float(ui) #посчитать сумму строки ui=input(">") и преобразовать её в float
        except: #вывести при белеберде юзера
            print("Некорректный ввод!")
```

Comment: чисто эстетически я бы привел сравнение ui к единому виду - `if ui in ["sum"]`, просто чтобы было одинаково со следующем сравнением, опять же задел на будущее, если вдруг надо будет еще и `"сумма"` вводить :)

Comment: @Zhihar Это какие то прям фантасмогорически красивые конструкции. Мне нравится) жаль что автор курса по которому я учу язык пока подобного не показывал, ну может в дальнейшем будет что-то подобное и от него

Comment: Голый `except:` съест синтаксические ошибки в блоке кода. Лучше `except ValueError:`.

Comment: т.е. если я использую где бы то ни было оператор `try:` `except:` лучше **всегда** использовать `except ValueError:` ?

Comment: Да, всегда лучше использовать самый конкретный `except`. Тип исключения меняется от задачи к задаче. В данном случае `ValueError`.

Comment: Я правильно понял что данный тип используется проверке чисел или символов который вводит юзер?

Answer (score -1):

Вот вам код

```
def start():
    nums = 0
    while True:
        text = input('> ')
        if text.isdigit():
            nums += int(text)
        if text == 'sum':
            print(nums)
            break
        elif text == 'exit':
             break
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ну и что? При запуске ничего нет. Не вызывается функция

Comment: И при вводе `sum` всё выключается.

Comment: Отрицательные числа всё сломают.